# Java - внешние файлы, .java , .class и расширение функционала

Tags: java, classloader

Итак, делаю не большой проект на **Java**, неважно какой, и появилась идея -- можно ли как-то импортировать / загрузить **внешний Java-файл в проект, и использовать его для расширения функционала текущей программы?**

Если конкретнее, проблема заключается в том, что есть проект, допустим он в папке:

> ...\projects\programa\ishodnik\

И есть некоторый сторонний (Не совсем сторонний, связанный по функционалу конечно) Java-файл который будет находиться в папке:

> ...\projects\programa\extensions\

Задача: Взять все файлы из этой папки, импортировать их в главный проект, и когда прейдет его время, **выполнить/использовать код/класс который находиться в этом файле.** Я видел кое-что про *classLoader* и *.class* файлы, но не уверен что это то, что мне нужно, не понял до конца, возможно -- плохо гуглил, не знаю. Ещё желательно чтобы это не требовало сильной подготовки, если это возможно, а работало без лишних действий со стороны пользователя, например -- появился файл (Пользователь его создал), программу запускаешь (Или она уже запущена) и она уже все делает, считывает и тд.

**----------Проблема решена-----------**

> Я бы задал ещё 1 вопрос, как запустить тот самый метод из уже скомпилированного скрипта с аргументами? И будет ли таким образом работать return (Из .class файла)

Оказалось все решается, как я понял, элементарно:

```
runMethod.invoke(null, argument1, argument2...);
```

А return можно принимать как-то так (не знаю, может фигню сделал, но это первое что пришло в голову):

```
int testReturn = (int)runMethod.invoke(null,  argument1, argument2);
```

***Всем ещё раз спасибо всем за помощь!***

Источник информации: [Компилирование и исполнение Java-кода в Runtime](https://habr.com/ru/post/688462/)

Comment: https://github.com/pf4j/pf4j или https://github.com/suvodeep-pyne/java-plugin-quickstart

Comment: дело даже не в том, можно ли єто сделать. а в том, что с вероятностью 99 процентов этого делать не надо. приведите конкретный пример, как вы хотите это использовать?

Comment: @Дмитрий Я ещё точно не уверен, буду ли я это вшивать в проект, но попробовать то надо! А там уже посмотрю, надо ли оно.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Спасибо, если не забуду, то посмотрю :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вижу три способа решить эту проблему:

1. Просто переместить `extensions` в ваш проект - проще всего.
2. Сделать корнем проекта папку `\projects\programa`. Тогда папка `\projects\programa\extensions` окажется в вашем проекте - тоже хороший способ.
3. Более сложный способ, но это как раз то, что вы хотели сделать. Упаковать в `jar` тот самый класс и подключить его как библиотеку к вашему проекту. Об есть множество информации в интернете, как это осуществить в каждой среде разработки.

Answer (score 0):

**ИТАК** Вот файл который я пытаюсь загрузить:

```
public class botCommand {
    public static void run() {
        System.out.println("HELLO! WORKS!");
    }
}
```

Когда я добавил в файл .java (Который я пытаюсь загрузить) ещё и

```
public class botCommand {
    public botCommand() {
    }

    public static void run() {
        System.out.println("HELLO! WORKS!");
    }
}
```

А в строчке кода:

`Class<?> loadedClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("testClass.testClass");`

Упростил все до:

`Class<?> loadedClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("testClass");`

Это заработало! ***Спасибо все кто помогал!***

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Теперь то это можно считать ответом на главный вопрос?

Comment: да, можно считать.